# MATLAB ifanbeam() reconstructs blurry image

Tags: matlab, tomography-reconstruction

we have been using the ifanbeam function to produce an image of a simulated phantom for medical X-ray imaging. The phantom consists of a water disc with three smaller discs inserted, made of bone, fat, and air. The phantom is positioned in the middle between a detector and an X-ray source (distance between detector and source is 5 cm). The X-ray beam is defined as a fan beam of 56 deg opening angle. The phantom rotates around its axis.
Our issue is that the reconstructed image looks blurry inside and it is difficult to see the smaller discs. [Image reconstructed using ifanbeam()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fV21s.png).

I've attached the ground truth image which I obtained from a different simulation using parallel beam rather than fan beam. [Ground truth image reconstructed using iradon()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwLdL.png)

The matlab code is below. After we preprocessed the raw data, we are creating a 3D array of size 180x240x20, which corresponds to an array of the single projections images of size 180x240. FYI, the raw data only consists of 10 projections, but we faced some issues with the FanCoverage parameter, so we padded the sinogram with zeros to artificially add another 10 projections and then setting FanCoverage to "cycle".

Did anyone have a similar problem before or knows how to help?

```
n=max(size(indices_time)); % indices_time corresponds to the number of events in the simulation 
images=zeros(180,240,nrOfProjections);
for m=1:n
    images(indices_y(m),indices_x(m),indices_time(m))=images(indices_y(m),indices_x(m),indices_time(m))+1;
end

sinogram=zeros(240,nrOfProjections*2);
for m=1:nrOfProjections
    sinogram(:,m)=sum(images(89:90,:,m));
end

theta=0:18:342;
figure(1)
colormap(gray)
imagesc(sinogram)
movegui('northwest')

rec_fanbeam=ifanbeam(sinogram,113.5,"FanCoverage","cycle","FanRotationIncrement",18,"FanSensorGeometry","line","FanSensorSpacing",0.25,"OutputSize",100);
figure(2)
colormap(gray)
imagesc(rec_fanbeam)
xlabel('xPos')
ylabel('yPos')
title('Reconstructed image')
movegui('northeast')
```

Comment: The entire field of computed tomography has the same issue, not just you! This is the sparse-view CT problem. Hospitals use from 300 to 700 projections, not 10! Why would they radiate (semi) healthy humans with so much X-ray dose if 10 would do? They would not, its just 10 projections simply does not do the job. You just opened up the door an entire field of research. Me and many others have been years at this.

Comment: Just do the experiment, try your code for different number of projections from 10 to 1000.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Ander. This is very true. However, the ground truth image I showed also only has 10 projections, so I should be able to reconstruct an image of this quality with the ifanbeam() as well.

Comment: Your recon image just looks like its from the wrong geometry. Due to the ill-posedness of  CT recon its quite hard to understand further by just looking at the image, but I'd start from that. Check pixel sizes, distances etc

Comment: Try also negative angles, conventions tend to differ on that.